# React <App /> component exists at sub-path on URL meaning testing-library cannot mock it because of react-router. How to fix?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

```
export const BASE_PATH = '/some-path';

...

import { BASE_PATH } from './some/place';

    <Routes>
        <Route path={`${BASE_PATH}/*`} element={<SomeComponent />} />
    </Routes>
```

In the integration test file:

```
const panel = render(<App />);
```

thereafter `testing-library` rightly complains that:

```
No routes matched location "/"
```

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Please, provide us a question that helps to understand what is the issue, add the relevant code of your test, of the mocking strategy and some details to help us helping you.

Comment: I've limited it to the essentials. all the routes in `<Router>` start with `BASE_PATH` and `render(<App ...)` in the integration test obviously doesn't have that. there is literally nothing more to add beyond irrelevancies

Comment: (I'm conscious that people have lives and don't want to spend a long time reading stuff)

Comment: Based on https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/ I can only assume you'd need to rewrite your code to wrap App in the router so you can test `<App />` and supply your own router which you can control the state of. And yes if you were to supply more code to indicate how App and your router  (i.e. `<BrowserRouter` or what you are using) relate that would be great

Comment: thanks @emanuele-scarabattoli ill add a little detail later (hopefully)

Comment: thanks @apokryfos ill add a little detail later (hopefully)

Comment: What are you testing? What is being tested? We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please edit your post to include a [mcve] so we've more context over what the code is doing and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

(I will get around to filling out the question asap. In the meanwhile...)

[apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) was right. Adding a App container like this:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { BASE_PATH } from './constants/constants-strings';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

const AppContainer = (props: any) => <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path={BASE_PATH} element={<App {...props} />} />
            <Route path={'*'} element={null} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>;

export default memo(AppContainer);
```

Means some child of `AppContainer` can then, say, implement this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={'/*'} element={<SomeComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

And then in an `integration.test.tsx` file you have this:

```
const app = render(<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path={'*'} element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>);
```